# Django UpdateView with unique fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.2

Is there a way to update a unique field in update view?
I have a model that has a `name` and `age` field but when I try to update the `age` without even changing the value of the `name`, it returns an error that the name already exists in the database

models.py

```py
class MyModel(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```py
class MyModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    def get(self):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        my_model = self.object

        form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model)

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(pk=my_model.pk, form=form)
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        my_model = self.object

        form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST, instance=my_model)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return some_url

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(pk=my_model.pk, form=form)
        )
```

forms.py

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'name',
            'age',
        )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        if MyModel.objects.filter(
            active=True, name=cleaned_data.get('name')
        ).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('MyModel already exists.')

        return cleaned_data
```

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you update a model, and you do not change the `name`, of course a record with that name already exists: *that* specific record. You thus should alter the checking code, to:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
        if MyModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).filter(
            active=True, name=cleaned_data.get('name')
        ).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('MyModel already exists.')
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'age')
```

Please do *not* alter the boilerplate logic of the `UpdateView`, you can easily implement this with:

```
class MyModelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = MyModelForm
    success_url = 'some url'
```

That being said, since if you already have *set* the field to `unique=True`, then there is no need to implement the check yourself. It seems here, that you already *have* a `unique=True` constraint:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

In that case, you can simply let the `ModelForm` do the work, so then your form looks like:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'age')
```

It is only if you want a more sophisticated uniqness (like with `active=True`?), and you can not represent it (easily) you should do your own validation.

Comment: ModelForms already handle uniqueness validation, there is no need to re-implement it

Comment: @IainShelvington: the problem here is that the `active=True` constraint should hold. That will not help if `unique=True` is set. It is thus a "conditional" uniqness.

Comment: Ah yes but in that case a row that has `active=False` and the same name would still fail uniqueness validation since the constraint is on the column. It shouldn't be possible to have 2 rows with the same name but 1 active and the other not

Comment: @IainShelvington: well the strange thing is that `active` is apparently not defined on the model. So the two somehow contradict each other. But it is correct that only in case you can not check uniqness with a `unique=True` (or `UniqueConstraint`, etc.) that you should implement the check. Updated the answer.